# Was able to view the rails start page after 'rails server', but unable to now on cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, puma, cloud9

I've tried to search for the answer to my question but couldn't find it.  Apologies if this has been answered already.

So I've been doing a Ruby on Rails course from Udemy, and after create an application, I decided to start from the beginning and recreating the application.

lol, I got stuck right at step one :(

So I went to my cloud9, went to my terminal where my rails projects were and created a new rails project

```
rails new myApp
```

Afterwards, I went into it `cd myApp`, then ran `rails server`

I noticed before, it would say `webBRICK`, but now it says `puma`

Also, I get this:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.4 application starting in development 
=> Run ' rails server -h ' for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Russell's Teapot
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:8080
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Usually, at the end of the 2nd line, there is `in development http://localhost:3000`  But I'm not getting that at all now.

I can't even go to the page to see that default rails page.  I've even tried manually entering it in with no luck.

So I'm just wondering, is there something I've done to change things?

I've tried multiple things.

`rails s -p $PORT -b $IP', 'killall ruby`,
 creating a new workspace

Sadly none of these or other solutions have worked.  It's annoyed me as I was able to see the rails page I made before but now, nothing happens/just can't even find the rails page.

(The course I did installed Heroku and github credentials.  I'm currently on a new workspace in cloud9).

Just wondering if there is anything else I can try?

Thanks

Comment: Try launching your rails server in a different port, like `rails s -p 3001`, what do you get?

Comment: I get:

`=> Booting Puma`

`=> Rails 5.1.4 application starting in development `

`=> Run 'rails server -h' for more startup options`

`Puma starting in single mode...`

`* Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.3.4-p301), codename: Russell's Teapot`

`* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5`

`* Environment: development`
`* Listening on tcp://localhost:3001`
`Use Ctrl-C to stop`

So the tcp://localhost port has changed.  When I click the tcp link, it still can't load the page (which I think is normal).  I used to have a http link that went to the default rails page, not sure where its gone now...

Comment: Resolved, I am using cloud9:

Make sure to run the rails server with:

`rails server -b 0.0.0.0`
or
`rails s -b $IP -p $PORT`

I then just ran the project using the green button at the top and found a link for my site:

https://name-of-workspace-username.c9users.io/